# Change progressbar color

Tags: delphi, lazarus

I have a progressbar in my form and I need to change its color. I need it to be Yellow and so I am using this code:

```
SendMessage(ProgressBar5.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, clYellow);
```

I am using Lazarus and I couldn't use the `SendMessage();` procedure. Then I have googled a bit and I found that I need to include in the uses the `lclintf` library.

Now I have another hassle because Lazarus can't recognize the parameter `PBM_SETBARCOLOR`. In fact it states:

```
unit5.pas(245,50) Error: Identifier not found "PBM_SETBARCOLOR";
```

I see that the first line of code that I wrote is the only way to change the color of a ProgressBar from green to the one I need.

Any help? I am using the latest version of Lazarus.

Comment: That's because that constant (and thus functionality) is specific to Windows. As you are using Lazarus, you're evidently not using Windows. Otherwise, if it is using the Windows API, then if you have themes enabled, it won't work either. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, a simple Google search gave me results such as this one: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=9545.0

Comment: @Jerry: "As you are using Lazarus, you're evidently not using Windows" Why is that?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I meant since Lazarus is a Linux-based language, its default compatibility is for Linux, and Windows is additional. As opposed to Delphi being Windows-based.

Comment: @JerryDodge: No, Lazarus is not a Linux-based language. You should probably do some research. The LCL is cross-platform, which includes Windows. The underlying language is FreePascal, which is also cross-platform (and therefore not Linux-based). `SendMessage` and `PBM_SETBARCOLOR` are Windows-specific, however, and therefore not cross-platform.

Comment: @KenWhite I see, it had always been my understanding that Lazarus was the Linux equivalent to Delphi. Of course it can compile for multiple platforms, but the IDE its self I thought was just Linux. Still, that's besides the point though, and we can only assume that OP is targeting Windows compilation.

Comment: @JerryDodge: You are thinking about Kylix, perhaps?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That's the one. I haven't touched Linux in years so all that's a blur.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Yep, Kylix was the official "Delphi for Linux" release from Borland, back around the time of Delphi 6/7. Lazarus is the Delphi 7 style IDE and VCL designed for use with FreePascal, which has no relation to Kylix whatsoever. (The ProgressBar and PBM constants seem to indicate the poster is using Windows, as does the inclusion of the Delphi tag, which until relatively recently was Windows only.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `PBM_SETBARCOLOR` is declared in the commctrl.pp unit of freepascal, same as in Delphi.

You could also declare it as a constant with value 1033 (WM_USER + 9).